# C# making SQL query on separate class for form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make query for datagridview from separate C# class. But I want to add textBox value of form2 on this query. How do I do this?

Usually, if I use

```
var f2 = Application.OpenForms.ofType<Form2>().Single();
```

on form1, I can get textbox value of form2 on form1 but on class, this doesn't work (var gets redlined). I am using windows form, and yes, I am actually using Excel file as database. Help.

I can call query1 string from form2 though.. but I can't get the form2 textbox value to this class test.

```
namespace test
{
    class query
    {
        var f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Single();
        public const string query1 = "Select * from [Sheet1$A2:Q] where Product like '" + f2.txt_Product.Text + "%'";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read about sql injection and use parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: You should explicit the type of f2, in place of var.

Comment: You should create a method in the `query` class and put the code in there.